# Sulu: Is there a way to create images programatically

Tags: sulu

Is there a way in Sulu CMS to create an image object programmatically without uploading an actual image through the admin interface?

The usecase is, that I would like to display a resized fallback image, if the user does not upload a header image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we made it by utilizing an image proxy ([Thumbor](http://thumbor.org/) in our case). This frees us from the image format restrictions of sulu and allows us to generate exactly the scaled / cropped versions of the file, that we need - all based on the original image url, that has been used for the upload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sulu_media.media_manager` service and give it a new UploadedFile instance e.g.:

```php
$mediaManager->save(
    new UploadedFile($path, $fileName, $mimeType),
    [
        'title' => 'Test',
        'locale' => 'de',
        'description' => '',
        'collection' => $collectionId,
        // ...
    ]
);
```

If performance matters or you need to import many files you should create the entities (media, files, fileVersion, fileVersionMeta) yourself and use the `sulu.media.storage` service to save the actually file which will return you the storageOptions e.g.:

```php
$media = new \Media();
$file = new File();
$file->setVersion(1);
$file->setMedia($media);
$media->addFile($file);

$mediaType = $this->entityManager->getReference(
    MediaType::class, $this->mediaTypeManager->getMediaType($this->getMimeType($uploadedFile))
);
$media->setType($mediaType);

$collection = $this->entityManager->getReference(Collection::class, $collectionid);)
$media->setCollection($collection);

$storageOptions = $this->mediaStorage->save($file->getPathname(), $fileName)
$fileVersion = new FileVersion();
$fileVersion->setVersion($file->getVersion());
$fileVersion->setSize($uploadedFile->getSize());
$fileVersion->setName($fileName);
$fileVersion->setStorageOptions($storageOptions);
$fileVersion->setMimeType(/* ... */);
$fileVersion->setFile($file);
$file->addFileVersion($fileVersion);
$fileVersionMeta = new FileVersionMeta();
$fileVersionMeta->setTitle($title);
$fileVersionMeta->setDescription('');
$fileVersionMeta->setLocale($locale);
$fileVersionMeta->setFileVersion($fileVersion);
$fileVersion->addMeta($fileVersionMeta);
$fileVersion->setDefaultMeta($fileVersionMeta);

$this->entityManager->persist($fileVersionMeta);
$this->entityManager->persist($fileVersion);
$this->entityManager->persist($file);
$this->entityManager->persist($media);

// after importing the files or after every 100 files you should flush the entitymanager
$this->entityManager->flush();
// I also recommend in a import doing a clear to keep the entitymanager unitofwork small as possible
$this->entityManager->clear();
```

The media type manager is available under `sulu_media.type_manager` and the doctrine entityManager `doctrine.orm.entity_manager`